# Exercise 2.5.6 in Grimmett & Stirzaker's 'Probability and Random Processes'

Tags: probability

The question asks:

Is the function $F(x,y) = 1 - e^{-xy}$ $0 \leq x,y \leq \infty$

The joint distribution function of some pair of random variables?

The answer is that is it not because it's second derivative is less than zero? I just want to make sure I understand the rationale. As the second derivative is negative this point it is a maximum but that would mean that the distribution function will decrease from that point violating the fact that a distribution function should be non decreasing. Is this the correct reasoning?

Comment: @Andrei Crusan F(0,0) = 0, not 1!

Comment: You are absolutely right, my mistake...

Comment: $F_X(x) = F_{X,Y}(x,\infty) = 1$ if $x\neq 0$ and $F_X(0) = 0$ (because if $F_{X,Y}$ is a cdf then $F_X$ is also a cdf for $X$). Hence $F_X$ wouldn't be right continuous at $x=0$. Hence $F_X$ cannot be a marginal df, hence $F_{X,Y}$ cannot be a cdf, where $F_{X,Y} (x,y) = F(x,y) = 1-e^{-xy}$

Comment: Second partial derivative of $F$ is the joint pdf of $(X,Y)$ if it exists, which can certainly be never negative.